# header.php-tweak: How to do that getting Meta-Slider into the header-center?

Tags: themes, css

update - the header.php in question: 
question is: where to add the new line

```
<?php 
echo do_shortcode("[metaslider id=36]"); ?>
```

at the moment i do not know where to add....

```
<?php

// Exit if accessed directly
if( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

/**
 * Header Template
 *
 *
 * @file           header.php
 * @package        Responsive
 * @author         Emil Uzelac
 * @copyright      2003 - 2014 CyberChimps
 * @license        license.txt
 * @version        Release: 1.3
 * @filesource     wp-content/themes/responsive/header.php
 * @link           http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Document_Head_.28header.php.29
 * @since          available since Release 1.0
 */
?>
    <!doctype html>
    <!--[if !IE]>
    <html class="no-js non-ie" <?php language_attributes(); ?>> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7 ]>
    <html class="no-js ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8 ]>
    <html class="no-js ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 9 ]>
    <html class="no-js ie9" <?php language_attributes(); ?>> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 9]><!-->
<html class="no-js" <?php language_attributes(); ?>> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>

        <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <title><?php wp_title( '&#124;', true, 'right' ); ?></title>

        <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11"/>
        <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>"/>

        <?php wp_head(); ?>
    </head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>


<?php responsive_container(); // before container hook ?>

    <?php echo do_shortcode("[metaslider id=85]"); ?>
<div id="container" class="hfeed">

<?php responsive_header(); // before header hook ?>
    <div id="header">

        <?php responsive_header_top(); // before header content hook ?>


        <?php if( has_nav_menu( 'top-menu', 'responsive' ) ) { ?>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
                                   'container'      => '',
                                   'fallback_cb'    => false,
                                   'menu_class'     => 'top-menu',
                                   'theme_location' => 'top-menu'
                               )
            );
            ?>
        <?php } ?>


        <?php responsive_in_header(); // header hook ?>

        <?php if( get_header_image() != '' ) : ?>

            <div id="logo">
                <a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>"><img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>"/></a>
            </div><!-- end of #logo -->

        <?php endif; // header image was removed ?>

        <?php if( !get_header_image() ) : ?>

            <div id="logo">
                <span class="site-name"><a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></span>
                <span class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></span>
            </div><!-- end of #logo -->


        <?php endif; // header image was removed (again) ?>


        <?php if( !get_header_image() ) : ?>

            <div id="logo">
                </div><!-- end of #logo -->

        <?php endif; // header image was removed (again) ?> 



        <?php get_sidebar( 'top' ); ?>
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
                               'container'       => 'div',
                               'container_class' => 'main-nav',
                               'fallback_cb'     => 'responsive_fallback_menu',
                               'theme_location'  => 'header-menu'
                           )
        );
        ?>

        <?php if( has_nav_menu( 'sub-header-menu', 'responsive' ) ) { ?>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
                                   'container'      => '',
                                   'menu_class'     => 'sub-header-menu',
                                   'theme_location' => 'sub-header-menu'
                               )
            );
            ?>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php responsive_header_bottom(); // after header content hook ?>

    </div><!-- end of #header -->
<?php responsive_header_end(); // after header container hook ?>

<?php responsive_wrapper(); // before wrapper container hook ?>
    <div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">
<?php responsive_wrapper_top(); // before wrapper content hook ?>
<?php responsive_in_wrapper(); // wrapper hook ?>
```

running wp 3.9.1
with the following things on a truely beta-page called http://www.maedchenhaus.org

theme 2014,
child-theme (twentyfourteen-child)
fourteen-colors-plugin

and the meta-slider-plugin
(( Easy to use slideshow plugin. Create SEO optimised responsive slideshows with Nivo Slider, Flex Slider, Coin Slider and Responsive Slides.
Version 2.8.1 | By Matcha Labs | Visit plugin site ))

well i want to place the plugin in the center of the header - - similar to the following site http://www.amadeu-antonio-stiftung.de/

is this possible?

note: as it is now - it looks funny.

i have put the plugin to the first posting - see it

and besides this i have tried to put the shortcode into the header - while editing the header.php.

But this looks pretty worhless.

well question: where do i have to edit the header.php - where to put the shortcode of the meta-slider?

love to hear from you
see the code that i have found out - while using firebug -

lemme know - where to add the shortcode to get the slider into the header - center.

**update** guess that i have to enter this code

```
<?php 
    echo do_shortcode("[metaslider id=36]"); 
?>
```

**end of update**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<body class="home blog logged-in admin-bar custom-background masthead-fixed list-view full-width grid customize-support">
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
<div id="main" class="site-main">
<div id="main-content" class="main-content">
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
<div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
<article id="post-7" class="post-7 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized">
```

see the header.php - and where i have edited it - well this is damned worthless. it makes no sense - no sense at all.

```
<?php
/**
 * The Header for our theme
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="main">
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="ie ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="ie ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7) | !(IE 8) ]><!-->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
    <?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
    <div id="site-header">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
            <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
        <div class="header-main">
            <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>

            <div class="search-toggle">
                <a href="#search-container" class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Search', 'twentyfourteen' ); ?></a>
            </div>

   [metaslider id=36]

            <nav id="primary-navigation" class="site-navigation primary-navigation" role="navigation">
                <button class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Primary Menu', 'twentyfourteen' ); ?></button>
                <a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentyfourteen' ); ?></a>
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <div id="search-container" class="search-box-wrapper hide">
            <div class="search-box">
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header><!-- #masthead -->
```

Comment: Did you try the plugins installation instructions for your theme http://www.metaslider.com/documentation/theme-integration/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a correct code into the header.php , currently you are putting [metaslider id=36] , which is not correct, you need to replace it with this:

```
<?php 
echo do_shortcode("[metaslider id=36]"); ?>
```

This of course suppose that you have the plugin activated and a slider created with an ID = 36.
I hope this will help

Comment: hello Duchi - many thanks !!! i tried to do so - but with the theme called repsonsive-pro (from cyperchimps ) i have no luck. Guess that i need to know where to include the specific line ... any and all hints will greatly be appreciated. greetings martin - btw i update in the initail posting the code of the header.php in question